# Parameter passing an Object instead of entire Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a simple Pokemon WinForm application with just 2 forms.  Form1 shows the Pokemon and its associated values.

[image]

Upon Clicking the Edit button, Form2 appears (EditCharacter) allowing the user to edit the attributes of the character.

[image]

To get the selected Pokemon to appear in Form2 (EditCharacter), I've passed in the currentCharacter from Form1.

Here is the code for **Form1**.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CardCollection cardCollection;
    public Character currentCharacter;
  
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cardCollection = new CardCollection();  
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        foreach (var keyValuePair in cardCollection.Cards)
        {
            cmbPokemon.Items.Add(keyValuePair.Key);
        }
    }

    private void cmbPokemon_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentCharacter = cardCollection.Cards[cmbPokemon.Text];
        updateControls();
    }

    public void updateControls()
    {
        lblHP.Text = currentCharacter.HealthPoints.ToString();
        lblStrength.Text = currentCharacter.Strength.ToString();
        lblSpecialPower.Text = currentCharacter.SpecialPower;
        pbPokemon.ImageLocation = @currentCharacter.FileName;
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditCharacter EditChar = new EditCharacter(currentCharacter);
        EditChar.ShowDialog();
    }       
}
```

And here is the code with Constructor for the **EditCharacter** form:

```
public partial class EditCharacter : Form
    {
        Character currentCharacter;
        public EditCharacter( Character c)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            currentCharacter  = new Character();
            currentCharacter = c;
            lblCharacter.Text = c.Name;
            pbCharacter.ImageLocation = c.FileName;
            txtPower.Text = c.SpecialPower;
            tbHP.Value = c.HealthPoints;
            tbStrength.Value = c.Strength;
            lblHP.Text = c.HealthPoints.ToString();
            lblStrength.Text = c.Strength.ToString();
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblHP.Text = tbHP.Value.ToString();
        }

        private void tbPower_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStrength.Text = tbStrength.Value.ToString();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentCharacter.Name = lblCharacter.Text;
            currentCharacter.FileName = pbCharacter.ImageLocation;
            currentCharacter.SpecialPower = txtPower.Text;
            currentCharacter.HealthPoints = tbHP.Value;
            currentCharacter.Strength = tbStrength.Value;
            currentCharacter.SpecialPower = txtPower.Text;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

My question is (and I've tried), how to preserve the values set in the EditForm to appear in Form1? For example, I edit Rayquaza's HealthPoints to 0, but when I return to Form1, it hasn't changed.

Comment: Someone could ask you the same question, why aren't you passing `currentCharacter` to this other Form? Change in `private Character currentCharacter;` and then `public EditCharacter(Character character)`

Comment: Tried that and ammended original post to show this. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you try to call a method that belongs to Form1 from this other Form that Form1 itself created? When `ShowDialog()` returns, call `updateControls();` from `Form1` -- You don't need a reference to `Form1` in `EditCharacter` -- Since you're using ShowDialog(), you should declare the new instance `EditCharacter` of like this: `using (EditCharacter EditChar = new EditCharacter(this);) { EditChar.ShowDialog(); updateControls(); }`

Comment: "Why would you try to call a method that belongs to Form1 from this other Form that Form1 itself created?"  Answer: trying to 'save' the new values for the Character so they'd appear back in Form 1.

Comment: Yes, that's the point, `updateControls();` belongs to Form1, so call it from there -- The snippet I've posted is of course not correct, should be: `using (var editChar = new EditCharacter(currentCharacter)) { editChar.ShowDialog(this); updateControls(); }`

Comment: Tried that - runtime error disappears but values are not preserved after changing them in the EditCharacter form.

Comment: Then show how you're initializing the edit Form and what `Character` object you're passing to it. Also show or describe the `Character` Type

Comment: You forgot to remove the `frm` variable.  Use the return value of ShowDialog() to decide if you should save the changes.

Comment: @Jimi Initializing the edit Form is shown in my original post (bottom) I'm passing in the currentcharacter selected by the combo box.    {  currentCharacter = cardCollection.Cards[cmbPokemon.Text];
            updateControls();  }

Comment: I've edited the original post to take into account the advice shown above - hopefully it has added a little more clarity.

Comment: You have `public EditCharacter(Character c)` and the `Character currentCharacter;` Field. You have to assign `c` to `currentCharacter`, then modify the latter, WITHOUT new-ing it, otherwise you create a new object that has no relation with the current character that Form1 passed in, which is represented by the `c` argument

Comment: @Jimi Ok, applied those changes, and these can be seen in OP in the EditCharacter form. Tested it again but changes not saved when I return to Form1.

Comment: You're not calling `updateControls();` when `.ShowDialog()` returns -- Remove this: `currentCharacter  = new Character();`

Comment: @Jimi  That has worked now - really appreciate your help Jimi.  Last question - I thought I needed to make a currentCharacter object hence the currentCharacter = new Character() line. Where else is currentCharacter instantiated then?

Comment: When you assign to it the already initialized object that Form1 passed in. It's a Reference Type, so you assign the pointer to this already existing object. After that, you operate on the original object through the local assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface to pass the same object directly to EditCharacter from and get it back when it has been updated.

1. Create new interface , that contains two methods one for reading and the other for writing.

   ```
   public interface ICharacterManager
   {
       Character ReadCharacterData();
       void WriteCharacterData(Character character);
   }
   ```
2. Update your Form1 code by applying ICharacterManager interface, like this :

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form , ICharacterManager
   {
       CardCollection cardCollection;
       public Character currentCharacter;

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           cardCollection = new CardCollection();
       }  

       // The  currentCharacter object which will be passed to EditCharacter form.
       public Character ReadCharacterData()
       {
           return currentCharacter;
       }

       // Get back Character object from EditCharacter form after updating data and pressing Save Button
       public WirteCharacterData(Character character) 
       {
           currentCharacter = character;

           // Call you updateControls() Method here.
           updateControls();
       }

       private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           // You can still  use this code, because already the type of Form1 is IChatacterManager now.
          EditCharacter EditChar = new EditCharacter(this);
          EditChar.ShowDialog();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Update your EditCharacter code by adding ICharacterManager variable like this :

   ```
    public partial class EditCharacter : Form 
    {
        private ICharacterManager _characterManager;
        Character currentCharacter;

        public EditCharacter(ICharacterManager characterManager)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _characterManager = characterManager;

            // Character object which come form Form1.
            currentCharacter = _characterManager.ReadCharacterData();

            lblCharacter.Text = currentCharacter.Name;
            pbCharacter.ImageLocation = currentCharacter.FileName;
            txtPower.Text = currentCharacter.SpecialPower;
            tbHP.Value = currentCharacter.HealthPoints;
            tbStrength.Value = currentCharacter.Strength;
            lblHP.Text = currentCharacter.HealthPoints.ToString();
            lblStrength.Text = currentCharacter.Strength.ToString();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentCharacter.HealthPoints = tbHP.Value;
            currentCharacter.Strength = tbStrength.Value;
            currentCharacter.SpecialPower = txtPower.Text;

            // Check if _characterManager object is not equal to null.
            if (_characterManager != null) 
            {
                // Pass the updated object back to Form1
                _characterManager.WriteCharacterData(currentCharacter);
            }

            this.Close();
        }
   ```

Hope this was helpful.

Happy coding :) ...

Comment: Hi Abubakr, thanks for this, but I'd like to solve the original problem (post) first using simple means before looking at interfaces.  I just seem to be struggling with returning and preserving values entered in EditCharacter form to show in Form1.

Comment: Hi @Tiny ,ok got it.  Do you try using "ref" keyword to pass Character object?

Comment: Pass it in your EditCharacter constructor , it will pass the same object , and when you change it in EditCharacter form , it should be updated also in Form1

`public EditCharacter(ref Character character) `

After EditCharacter Dialog closes you can call updateControls() method to update Form1.